# Selectively displaying data into the Long Text Viewer

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have four levels of report filters: Month, Year, Region and Country, all of which were set as Page Level and Report Level filters.

The data is structured like so:
[image: data]

And basically, this is how it looks like if all slicers are set to All:
[image: result]

This is obviously not helpful and doesn't really give proper context to the data if viewed by anyone since it just listed down everything in the Comment column.

So is it possible to selectively display data from the Comment field into the Long Text Viewer (ie: display nothing if all Slicers were set to All, only display comments for the particular country/month, etc.)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how you want the exact display logic to be, you may find the [HASONEFILTER()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492135.aspx) and [HASONEVALUE()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492190.aspx) function useful in this case.

The following is an example where a new `measure` is created, and it'll display the comment (concatenated by newline which will be handled later) when there are any filters applied to the column `Month`, `Year` or `Country`; or it'll return an empty string.

```
Useful comment = 
IF(
    HASONEFILTER(Data[Month]) || HASONEFILTER(Data[Year]) || HASONEFILTER(Data[Country]),
    CONCATENATEX(Data, Data[Comment], "\n"),
    ""
)
```

The `Long Text Viewer` provides a format option called `Newline starts with`, which allows us to split the measure we created (which is a long concatenated string containing all filtered comments) back to separate lines for display purpose.

[image: format]

The following shows the result when no filter is applied:
[image: no filter]

The following shows the result when filter is applied:
[image: filter]

---

EDIT:

Same result when slicer is a dropdown:

[image: dropdown]

Another example, display nothing when year is 2016:

```
Useful comment 2 = 
IF(
    CONTAINS(DATA, DATA[Year], "2016"),
    "",
    CONCATENATEX(DATA, DATA[Comment], "\n")
)
```

When Year = 2016:

[image: 2016]

When Year = 2017:

[image: 2017]

Comment: Hi Foxan! Thank you for the help! I checked this with my visualization and I think this only works with list slicers and not dropdown list slicers. Is it possible to check for the value of a slicer? Ie: if the year slicer = 2016 then do not display anything?

Comment: @RemiDarren List or dropdown slicer is just a display difference. It has nothing to do with the logic behind so the solution should work as is.

Comment: @RemiDarren I've also added example to the Year = 2016 question. It's easier to think in "table" rather than think in "slicer". When you pick a value in the slicer, you're applying filter to the particular table. So in the measure, you can write something like "If the particular column contains such value (after filtering), then..". Essentially, you're checking the value against the table but not the slicer. Please check and accept the answer if it works for you.

Comment: Okay, this one worked for me: `IF(HASONEFILTER(Productivity_Data[Country]) && HASONEFILTER(Productivity_Data[Month]), CONCATENATEX(Productivity_Data, Productivity_Data[Comment], "\n\n"), "Please select only one Country from the list")`.

Comment: @RemiDarren Can you accept the answer if it solves your problem?